# react-native-paper DataTable: how to align header columns width with table cell width in React Native App?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, datatable, react-native-paper

I am making a data grid in my react native app, I have created arrays to make header columns and grid data, both are different variables which are mapped `.map()`, find my code below.

Now since the header columns and cell grid data are differently mapped so how we can create an equal sized columns of both header and data so it will look like a normal table grid, please check [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3WKe.png) how my table looks like.

And here is my code:-

```
const columns = [
  {
    id: "tran_id",
    title: "Tran No.",
    size: 100,
  },
  {
    id: "company_name",
    title: "Company Name",
    size: 100,
  },
  {
    id: "username",
    title: "Username",
    size: 100,
  },
  {
    id: "first_name",
    title: "FirstName",
    size: 100,
  },      
];


<DataTable.Header style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}>
              {columns.map((el) => {
                return (
                  <DataTable.Title
                    style={[styles.header, { width: el.size }]}
                    key={el.id}
                    numberOfLines={2}
                  >
                    <Text style={styles.tableHeading}>{el.title}</Text>
                  </DataTable.Title>
                );
              })}
            </DataTable.Header>
            <ScrollView style={{ backgroundColor: "#fff" }}>
              {gridData.slice(from, to).map((el) => {
                return (
                  <DataTable.Row key={el.tran_id}>
                    <DataTable.Cell numeric style={styles.cells}>
                      {el.tran_id}
                    </DataTable.Cell>
                    <DataTable.Cell numeric style={styles.cells}>
                      {el.company_name}
                    </DataTable.Cell>
                    <DataTable.Cell numeric style={styles.cells}>
                      {el.username}
                    </DataTable.Cell>
                    <DataTable.Cell numeric style={styles.cells}>
                      {el.first_name}
                    </DataTable.Cell>                   
                  </DataTable.Row>
                );
              })}
            </ScrollView>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  cells: {
    padding: 8,
    borderRightWidth: 1,
    borderLeftWidth: 1,
    borderRightColor: Colors.grey500,
    borderLeftColor: Colors.grey500,
    borderStyle: "solid",
  },
header: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey300,
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    borderStyle: "solid",
    borderRightWidth: 1,
    borderRightColor: Colors.grey500,
    paddingRight: 15,
    paddingLeft: 15,
    textAlign: 'left',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start'
  },
```

I have created a `size` key in the columns as you can see to add the size of the column, I was trying to use this method but I don't know how to manage cell width along with the header columns.
How to do that?